# How to string match in SQL(Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sql-like

TABLE_1 has 5 strings like these : 'AK___', 'AB_DE', 'AB__E', 'AE__E', 'AF___'

One underscore stands for any one letter or number.

If given 'ABZDE'`,

is there a way to select 'AB_DE', 'AB__E' in my Table_1?

```
create table TABLE_1 ( modelname varchar2(10) )

INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES ('AK___')
INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES ('AB_DE')
INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES ('AB__E')
INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES ('AE__E')
INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES ('AF___')

SELECT * 
FROM Table_1 
WHERE modelcode like 'AEZDE'  --of course, this select clause doesn't work as I expected.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcards are in the `modelcode` column, so it needs to be the right hand argument of the `like` operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Table_1 
WHERE  'AEZDE' like modelname
-- Here ------------^
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misusing the LIKE operator; it needs the wildcard characters.  I believe the structure of the query you're looking for is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_1 
WHERE modelcode like '%AE%DE%'
```

But I'm not sure.  Do the letters change between your question and your code?

Comment: My question seemed ambiguous. So I've just edited my question. String has 5 letters(fixed). Thanks for your reply